# How to disable the screenshot sound effect on Android 12 (and above)?

Tags: audio, android-12, screenshots

To my knowledge there's no such setting in AOSP, having combed through the system options in several major LineageOS (19 at the time) and CyanogenMod releases.

The only method I know is to delete the related file (I've also wiped the entire folder contents) in `/system/product/media/audio/ui/` using root or alternative using the 'do not disturb mode' at all times.

The stock camera app (e.g. `com.android.camera2`) may or may not have an option to turn off the shutter sound.

Comment: [a question about Android 11 and Google Pixel 3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230833/how-to-disable-sound-during-screenshot-in-android-11-on-pixel-3)